# Push ups-Wrist strain?

Tags: injury-prevention, push-ups, chest, calisthenics, wrist

I used to do 200 push ups a day but I have heard that they put a tremendous amount of strain on your wrists so I decided not to do them often anymore. Is this true, or just a myth?

Comment: Are you doing them on your palms or on your knuckles?

Comment: Regardless if it’s a true, or, a myth, I think the important point here is the potential for an ‘overuse’ syndrome.  Doing 200 push-ups every day seems pretty excessive to me.  Couple that with any other fitness training you may be doing and I’d say your wrists are in constant recovery mode.  Why not just cut back on the volume?

Comment: I'm inclined to say that, if you were able to do 200 pushups a day, and weren't feeling any strain, odds are that your wrists are fine with it.

Comment: Do you have access to a gym? Why not do reps of 6-10 on a bench press for example to save your wrists? What is your goal with the push-ups?

Comment: Incorporating different varations ex. fingertipp push-ups, inclean etc. And some wrist specific strength training like using rise-buckets helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you can hurt your wrist by doing push-ups on your wrist for too long.  200 push ups, if in a single session, seems a little bit too much to me.

You can alleviate a lot of the pressure by using push-up handles (bars). Also, remember to wear a pair of gloves, it is good for your palm.